# algorithm for huge file parsing

Tags: algorithm

I have a huge file approximately of size 1 gb with the given format. Each line has two number.
Now the task is to determine that the number given by the user, lies within the  range.
As the file is huge, It is taking large time .. Any algorithm insight will be helpful to reduce time factor.

```
    #1 2 
    #3 5
    #6 7 
    #7 41 
    #7  8 
    #9 41 

    Input : 4,8,9

    OUTPUT

    #1 2  
    #3 5 #4
    #6 7 
    #7 41 #8,9 
    #7  8 #8
    #9 41 #9
```

Comment: What language/framework are you using? What does your current file reading code look like?

Answer (score 1):

If there are just a few inputs nothing will be faster than scanning the whole file and for each line checking each number individually. If there are many inputs (>= 20) you can sort them and check using binary search if the lower and upper numbers of each line overlap with the range of input numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a index file that will have the file_seek location for each/some start values. This way you can jump right into part of the file that is relevant.